# Screen (slowly) goes black after full-screening apps

Tags: nvidia, graphics

Whenever I full-screen certain applications, my entire screen will slowly begin to get covered by a black filter from the top down (see [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGtjY5-KWp0)).

Upon any attempt at a screen refresh (for example, moving a mouse cursor or a game drawing a new frame) will cause the black bar to start from the top again. Doing this may also cause flickering and discoloration on the screen.

Certain applications (like Firefox and the terminal) will not exhibit this behavior, but others (like Google Chrome, Discord, and various games) will. No applications exhibit this behavior when running on the Nouveau driver.

Going back to a constantly-redrawing application (like the Unity desktop) will cause the black screen to not advance anymore, but it will also cause some slight flickering that will fade with time.

I am not able to take a screenshot or record it. This suggests to me that this is something lower-level than the X server or my display manager.

This error does not seem to occur on a guest session (or I have not been able to reproduce it there yet), suggesting something related to a bad configuration is at play. However, creating a new account *will* bring this bug with it.

What is going on? Is this just a driver bug? Is this a configuration error that just needs fixing somehow?

**Current List Of Things Tried™ (that didn't work):**

- Reset all Unity configs
- Delete NVIDIA settings file and regenerate
- Uninstall/reinstall NVIDIA drivers
- Using older NVIDIA drivers
- Using an alternate display manager (`xdm`)

Disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome does allow it to function without this issue, but this still doesn't solve the underlying problem - it's not always an option to disable hardware acceleration.

If possible, I'd rather avoid resetting a profile or switching back to open-source drivers. These are both last-resorts in my mind and I still won't know *why* this happened, meaning I can't report a bug or avoid accidentally triggering it on my new profile if I go down that route.

---

**Operating System:** Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
**Kernel:** 4.10.0-36-generic, 4.11.0-14-generic
**Graphics Card:** Nvidia GTX 1080 (Not Optimus)
**GC Driver:** NVIDIA 387.12, repro with 384.90 and 381.22

Comment: So the issue doesn't occur when you use `nouveau` and it doesn't occur when you use either `nvidia` or `nouveau` with a guest user, am I right there? You have no idea when this started and what you may have done back then, do you?

Comment: I did not notice it with nouveau, though I do admit to not testing that thoroughly. I also was not able to reproduce it in the guest session. I will go and test that just to be sure.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67022/screen-slowly-goes-black-after-full-screening-apps

Comment: Deleted answer as it doesn't seem to work. Ping me if no one can find a solution.  Also ping me in chat some time when I'm on-line so we can investigate more thoroughly....

Comment: @Fabby Please feel free to join the chatroom Dessert linked above, and I will answer any and all questions about it as soon as I can.

Comment: Did you overclock your graphics card? if so check if its overheating and may want to revert those settings back. Sounds like you are pulling too much from the graphics and its luckily not crashing but slowly paginating. Chrome is a resource hog and would easily repeat the issue unlike firefox which is not nearly as resource hungry. Terminal isn't graphics heavy and thus likely why its not experiencing it either. Of course unity is resource hog too so makes sense too. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Software_Programineer There is no active overclock and thermal is staying below 65 deg C. Chrome in the guest session does not do it, and Unity in general does not experience this issue. On chrome, I do not experience any issue when using resource-intensive browser applications in windowed mode, though even `about:blank` fullscreen will cause this issue.

Comment: @dessert Ok, I just confirmed fully that this does not happen with Nouveau. It has to be something with NVidia's drivers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enable **Force Composition Pipeline** or **Force Full Composition Pipeline** on the affected screen from the `nvidia-settings` app.

[image: Thing to click]

Following this, click **Apply**. The screen may flicker momentarily, but the problem will be resolved immediately afterwards.

---

Alternatively, if you'd rather not have a true `Xorg.conf` file (usually a good idea), simply place the following into `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf` (create if it does not exist):

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"
EndSection
```

Restart your display manager using `systemctl restart lightdm.service` and it will work perfectly.

---

**Disclaimer:** I have no idea how this fixes the issue. It just does.